# How do you run the official flutter animations example package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-packages

I am trying to run the examples shown on the official animations plugin page for flutter here

https://pub.dev/packages/animations

The instructions are seemingly simple but I can’t seem to do it. It says

“ To see examples of the following animations on a device or simulator:

cd example/
flutter run --release@ “

My question is how do you do the above instruction exactly?

I tried creating a new Flutter project and tried cd example/ assuming it was hidden file.

I also tried looking for a url to clone the git repo but found nothing...

In short how do I get those examples on the animations as a flutter project and run them?

Comment: They area talking about this [one](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/master/packages/animations)

Answer (score 1):

the example folder is not hidden, it is the folder of your project you should cd 'your flutter project path here' and then run the command run --release.
you will get the starter boilerplate for a flutter project, if you want the actual examples you should check the examples tab and copy what's in there in your main.dart file [image]

also if you want the link to the github repo press on the link in blue that says example/lib/main.dart.[image]